# Parse SDK exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject

Tags: java, android, parse-server

I am doing a query to get the count of records in a table. But everytime I try filter any "Pointer" field, I get the error:

My query:

```
ParseXpto.getQuery()
.whereEqualTo("story", ParseXpto.getStory(o.getObjectId()))
.whereEqualTo("installation", ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation())
.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
         //java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to encode an association with an unsaved ParseObject
    }
});
```

I did some tests and I know that the error happens when I use `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation()`.

I have a Pointer on my ParseXpto to Pointer<_Installation> class, so I need filter this field.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please post a complete code example. In Java, all code must be in a method in a class. Be sure to indicate which line of code throws the exception.

Comment: this is the block that throw the error, its a background operation, error come in ParseException parameter

Comment: @Shmuel parse server shut down. Parse SDK is open source and you can host in a parse server.

Comment: **you can host in a parse server**, but not firebase.